# Host Project on Public GitHub Repo but Hide Sensitive Information

Tags: github, version-control

So I'm fine with the source code to my files being public, but I obviously don't want my passwords/login info/etc to be public.

How can I host the repo with GitHub publicly but keep myself safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, all config data like passwords and database info will be kept in a config file. To keep private data safe, I usually:

- Create an example config file that is hosted with the project
- Provide documentation on modifying the example to be the actual config (rename the file, replace variables, etc.)
- Add the actual config file to `.gitignore` so that it is not a tracked file

Those are my thoughts ...

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two ways:

- Don't use Git, here such *obvious task* is **problem**, and move to Mercurial with MQ, in which you store in public place any scrap, replaced in local workplace by actual data (local MQ-patches)
- Read about [smudge/clean filters](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) and store in repository template-snippets, expanded automagicaly to real data in Working Directory

Comment: If the question implies using git, the not using git isn't an answer.

Comment: @SteveRobbins - I wrote "You have at least **two** ways...", BTW. Templating and handwork is old style, filters - Git-way, JFYI

Answer (score 0):

I like to configure all my apps from the environment.  This allows for a clean separation of code and environment - see [The 12-Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

In a Rails project, for example, I'll check in the `secrets.yml` file with these contents (as an example):

`development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>`

Then all of the configuration happens in my environment.  There's also a handy gem for Rails that will load a `.env` file with variables for my environment called `dot-env`.  This file is never checked in (but a `.env.example` file is provided with placeholder values).

When the app is deployed the tools will make sure to configure the environment before deploying the code.